# updating multiple rows of 2 columns with different values (db2 sql)

Tags: db2

I have a table in which I need to change the values of a couple of columns in multiple rows.

The table with values to be changed is like:

[image: table structure]

The code I have tried containing updated values, with no success, is:

```
UPDATE <table_name>
SET (IDENTIFIER_1, IDENTIFIER_2) 
VALUES (1635, 1755),
       (2024, 2199),
       (1868, 1692),
       (3577, 4825)
WHERE ID 
        IN ('1', 
            '23', 
            '54', 
            '21');
```

To be honest, I am not sure if this is even supported in db2 SQL. The error is:

> - [Error Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=update *

I should also advise that I am a db2 newbie.

Comment: I ended up splitting the query into separate UPDATE SET statements for each of the values to be changed. It definitely isn't a recommended solution, but for only 4 records it worked for me. The revised code is: `UPDATE <table_name> SET (IDENTIFIER_1, IDENTIFIER_2) = (1635, 1755) WHERE ID = 1`... and repeated the same for the other 3 records.

Comment: Your "update values" are "original value" + 1 all the time - is that a rule? Such information would help to solve your problem.

Comment: No, I just happened to increment all the values by 1 in my testing. The changed values could be something other than an increment of 1. Thanks for checking Michael.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use Merge

```
MERGE INTO TABLE1                                               
USING  (                                                        
VALUES (1,1635, 1755),                                          
               (23,2024, 2199),                                 
               (54,1868, 1692) ) dummytable(ID_T, INF1,INF2)    
on table1.id_table  = dummytable.id_t                           
when matched                                                    
   then UPDATE set  TABLE1.IDENTIFIER_1 = dummytable.INF1       
     , TABLE1.IDENTIFIER_2 = dummytable.INF2                    
 else ignore
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! As noted, I am a db2 sql newbie, so this info is helpful to me.

Comment: @Randy Anytime, if you got what you are looking for please accept and close the question :)

Comment: Done, with apologies. Apparently I am also a newbie at following protocol on Stackoverflow. :-)